# How can i attach a Event when the Window close button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

"**beforeunload**" or "**onunload**" event also executes when page is Refreshed. But i need to attach a Event Handler that perform only when user press the "Close" button of the Window or Tab. Is there any way?

Comment: Short answer: not possible, there is simply no such event.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do that with `onclose` event:

```
window.onclose = doSomthing;
```

Comment: [`onclose`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/close_websocket) doesn't seem suitable ...

Comment: @Teemu i was referring to this [onclose event.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclose)